# Generate a node/edge matrix from long data or single columns of variables (or other shared analyses)

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, tidyr

I am trying to find the number of shared and unique features between several clusters (nodes) and visualize them. The data I have is in 2 columns. I think I need to get it into target/source format but I cannot figure it out from this current format.

Here is some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(cluster = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5)),
                 feature = c(letters[1:3], letters[7:8], letters[1:3], letters[9:10], letters[2:3], letters[9:11]))

> df
   cluster feature
1        1       a
2        1       b
3        1       c
4        1       g
5        1       h
6        2       a
7        2       b
8        2       c
9        2       i
10       2       j
11       3       b
12       3       c
13       3       i
14       3       j
15       3       k
```

I want to show that cluster `1` shares `a` with 1 other cluster, cluster `1` shares `b` with 2 other clusters, cluster `2` shares `i` with cluster `3` etc.

I have tried so many combinations of tidyr, plyr, dplyr code but I can't figure it out. For example this basic code gives me the number of shared partners between clusters, but not which partner it is shared with.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(feature) %>%
  mutate(n_gene = n())


> df2
# A tibble: 15 × 3
# Groups:   feature [8]
   cluster feature n_gene
     <dbl> <chr>    <int>
 1       1 a            2
 2       1 b            3
 3       1 c            3
 4       1 g            1
 5       1 h            1
 6       2 a            2
 7       2 b            3
 8       2 c            3
 9       2 i            2
10       2 j            2
11       3 b            3
12       3 c            3
13       3 i            2
14       3 j            2
15       3 k            1
```

My goal is to have either a network like something below (credit to [DiVenn](https://github.com/BCH-RC/DiVenn)) or another similar visualization where I can show number of shared features between each cluster pair.

Thank you.

red dots represent unique and shared features between cluster nodes:
[image: red dots represent unique and shared features between cluster nodes]

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't compatible with the packages you are using, that's why you are getting errors.

For visualizing a network you need a matrix with nodes. Something like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     0
 [2,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1     0
 [4,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    1     0
 [7,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
[10,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1     0
```

1 represents that there is an edge and 0 represents that there isn't an edge.

Using the `ggnet2` package you can visualize this kind of network. The code looks like this:

```
net = rgraph(10, mode = "graph", tprob = 0.5)
net = network(net, directed = FALSE)

# vertex names
network.vertex.names(net) = letters[1:10]
ggnet2(net)
```

The graph looks like following:

[image]

I tried plotting your graph using `iagraph` as well. What it does is, create a node between a cluster and a feature that is wrong but still, I'll include it to show you what's wrong.

```
library(igraph)
df.g <- graph.data.frame(d = df, directed = TRUE)
df.g
plot(df.g, vertex.label = V(df.g)$name)
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
df %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  set_vertex_attr(
    name = "color",
    value = c("green", "red")[1 + (names(V(.)) %in% df$feature)]
  ) %>%
  plot()
```

[image]